# Banach Tarski paradox in Minkowski space

Tags: differential-geometry, set-theory, euclidean-geometry

The Banach - Tarski paradox states:
'A three-dimensional Euclidean ball is equidecomposable with two copies of itself.'
My simple question is: Does this paradox hold his validity also in the Minkowski space in which there are four dimensions and one of them is imaginary? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Just decompose a threedimensional cross-section and "spread" the result.

Comment: What do you mean by a ball in Minkowski space?  Do you mean the set of all points $(x,y,z,t)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +t^2 < 1$ or $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - t^2 < 1$?

Comment: @Nate: the second one.

Comment: Actually, it does not matter what set you take, they are both equidecomposable.